# Relation between Casimir Effect and Quantum Tunnelling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling, casimir-effect

Are Casimir Effect and Quantum Tunnelling dependent on each other? Also, is it reasonable to conclude that if Casimir Effect is already observed in a system, then Quantum Tunnelling has also taken place (or vice versa)? Alternatively, can both the phenomena be observed simultaneously in a single system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic answer:

Casimir effect and Quantum Tunneling are independent of each other - unless you want to view the probabilistic behavior of quantum world as the common factor in both phenomena.

Quantum tunneling is when a quantum particle "surmounts" a potential wall with energy larger than the energy of the particle. 
Casimir effect is the apparent attraction of two plates, which is due to quantum fluctuations (appearance and annihilation of particles) and limiting of particles of certain energies inside the plates.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the explanation therein. If it isn't a silly request for clarification, would like to ask whether it's possible to observe Casimir effect in the plates separated by a potential wall between them?

Comment: Inserting a potential wall (practically speaking another plate in between the first two plates) will just rearrange the Casimir plate setup.  I'd say the effect  will be still there.

Answer (score -1):

In lame words-Do consider the effect of dipole dipole interaction on electric field fluctuations and the potential due to this interaction in vacuum space. Then consider the tunneling probability into a potential wall by by considering all the potentials created( including pertubed terms)..It does affect the tunneling rate.
You can know it by applying a electric field to two nano films kept a distant apart. Observe the response. Infact particles (bosons and fermions) do tunnel.